# Check if request comes from server or browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-cors

Using Rails in API mode. Also have the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem installed with my own domains whitelisted. I'd also like to minimally secure my API with an API key added to requests made from a server .

I suspect this might be a stupid question, but is there a way I can set up my API where I only need to check for the presence of an API key in the header if the request is coming from a server? As I understand it, the rack-cors gem just protects me from ajax requests from non-whitelisted domains, right?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the user_agent like this:

```
request.user_agent
```

And see what's that value for your server and if it's different from the bowsers, it will be easy to do the condition. Hope this helps!