# How to check on a server that a http request is coming from a web browser?

Tags: http-headers, cloudflare-workers

How can I check on a server (cloudflare worker) that a http request is coming from a web browser, rather than something like curl - are there headers I can check, or is there a better way?

ChatGPT recommends:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const userAgent = event.request.headers.get('User-Agent');
  if (userAgent && userAgent.includes('Mozilla') && userAgent.includes('AppleWebKit')) {
    // Request is likely from a web browser
    // Handle the request accordingly
  } else {
    // Request is not from a common web browser
    // Handle it differently or deny access
  }
});
```

However is that bulletproof, is there a better way? Does cloudflare provide its own headers I can check?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/50068724/130638 — which doesn't have any good answers on it.

Comment: Cloudflare Headers: https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/reference/http-request-headers/

Nothing there related to browser vs non-browser

Comment: There is no bulletproof way. Any header that a browser can send can also be sent with curl or similar applications.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Cloudflare's page protection relies on running a JS challenge before deciding to pass the request, but the HTTP request is pretty much indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I went with:

```js
request.headers.get('Accept').includes('html')
```

As the purpose of why I wanted such a check, is to send plaintext to things like curl/wget/etc (which don't send an Accept header by default), and to send a redirect to a html page for web browsers (which send an Accept header that accepts html).